# Cannot compile with Firebase typings (typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I did:

```
npm install firebase --save
typings install npm~firebase --save
```

and the typings.json looks like this:

```
{
"ambientDevDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
},
"ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654"
},
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "registry:npm/firebase#3.0.5+20160723033700"
}
}
```

I'm importing Firebase in a *.ts file like this:
`import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

but when I compile I get:

```
src/app/services-common/database.service.ts (2, 27): Cannot find module 'firebase'.
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (C:\testapp\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:120:19)
```

How can I solve this? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, [those typings are problematic](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/234).

Per [angularfire2 docs](http://%20https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md), here's something you can try:

Install angularfire2 if you haven't already:

```
npm install angularfire2 --save
```

Include Firebase SDK typings:

```
typings install file:node_modules/angularfire2/firebase3.d.ts --save --global && typings install
```

Your typings.json file (or at least the firebase line) should look like [this one](https://github.com/r-park/todo-angular2-firebase/blob/master/typings.json), which is a project that uses firebase3, angular2 and works perfectly.